Handle Optional to Optional mapping
What is the best way to map Optional to Optional in a generic way and not do a manually mapping for every Optional?
e.g.
Optional<PersonDto> mapDto(Optional<Person> person)
Optional<Integer> mapInt(Optional<Integer> person)

EDIT:
Currently what I tried
public abstract class DefaultOptionalMapper<E, D> {

   public abstract D entityToDTO( E entity );

   public abstract E dtoToEntity( D dto );

   public Optional<D> optionalEntityToOptionalDTO( final Optional<E> optionalEntity ) {
      return optionalEntity.map( this::entityToDTO );
   }

   public Optional<E> optionalDTOToOptionalEntity( final Optional<D> optionalDTO ) {
      return optionalDTO.map( this::dtoToEntity );
   }

}


I wrote an updated answer.

Using stream api it's possible, but it's necessary to write java code. MapStruct is good for mapping fields, also default values, constants, some checks, but not for dynamic mapping, here it's necessary to right native java code.
Something like:
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

public interface GenericMapper {
    static <T, U> Optional<U> mapOptional(Optional<T> source, Function<T, U> mapper) {
        return source.map(mapper);
    }
}

And in your code it would look like :
Optional<Person> person = Optional.of(new Person("John", 30));
Optional<PersonDto> personDto = GenericMapper.mapOptional(person, p -> new PersonDto(p.getName(), p.getAge()));


Not sure if that what Iam looking for. I would not copy the whole attributes

I use DTOs how you see in my example. I see no reason why MapStruct should not handle a Optional to a Optional mapping from a domain object to a DTO object. It is the same like a mapping without Optional just call getter and setter

@MelleD If you want simpler implementation, and more efficient, if you would be to map using mapStruct, personDto to person and vice versa, then just call optional whenever you need it, otherwise it's an overkill.

Sorry I don't get it why it should be a overkill to do that. It's a simple mapping operation

What i mean is :
Mapping should be between : Person toPeronDto(PersonDto personDto);
And then calling optional.
The reason is exactly what you mentioned, it's because it's a simple operation.

Nevermind you solution and mine works fine.
I found the issue with a MRE why the inner Optional was not mapped
The domain object have constructor without Optional only the setter have Optional, but if a constructor is available mapstruct use this first, although the setter would be more suitable. And there are two options:
a) make constructor with optional
b) create a OptionaMapper for T map(Optional) etc.
Thanks for your help
